# terms query does not support multiple fields

Tags: json, elasticsearch, search

Is there a way to write an OR query that matches using terms with field1 (or) matches using terms with field2....
Getting a message "[terms] query does not support multiple fields"...there ought to be a way:-

```
       "constant_score":{  
          "filter":{  
             "bool":{  
                "should":{  
                   "terms":{  
                      "field1 ":[  
                         "017M0",
                         "000XXJ0900"
                      ],
                      "field2":[  
                         "017M0",
                         "000XXJ0900"
                      ]
                   }                       
                }
             }
          }
       }
```

Answer (score 3):

using should as an OR clause and having multiple terms defined like below..solved my issue.

```
            "bool":{  
                  "should": [
                    {
                      "terms": {
                        "field1": [ "017M0v", "000XXJ0900v" ]
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "terms": {
                        "field2": [ "017M0", "000XXJ0900"]

                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
```